# Java Equivalent of C++ .dll?

Tags: java, c++, dll

So, I've been programming for a while now, but since I haven't worked on many larger, modular projects, I haven't come across this issue before.

I know what a .dll is in C++, and how they are used.  But every time I've seen similar things in Java, they've always been packaged with source code.  For instance, what would I do if I wanted to give a Java library to someone else, but not expose the source code?  Instead of the source, I would just give a library as well as a Javadoc, or something along those lines, with the public methods/functions, to another programmer who could then implement them in their own Java code.

For instance, if I wanted to create a SAX parser that could be "borrowed" by another programmer, but (for some reason--can't think of one in this specific example lol) I don't want to expose my source.  Maybe there's a login involved that I don't want exploited--I don't know.

But what would be the Java way of doing this?  With C++, .dll files make it much easier, but I have never run into a Java equivalent so far. (I'm pretty new to Java, and a pretty new "real-world" programmer, in general as well)

Comment: all Java can be de-compiled very easily so if you embed passwords you aren't really hiding them from anyone that really wants to know them.

Comment: Matt, Note that a `.dll` is not "in C++" it is a Windows thing, which can be created from several different languages. The Unix/Linux equivalent is a `.so` (shared object) library.

Comment: your tittle doesn't match your comment.... simple have a source jar and a code jar. but, as other people pointed out you can obfuscate the code if you don't want people to read it, it's a pain for other people using your library as they would need the mappings in order to compile and the obfuscator.

A dll is a shared library across multiple program
A jar is a shared library across one program (new instance per program)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Java `.jar` library is the Java equivalent of .dll, and it also has "Jar hell", which is the Java version of "dll hell"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Jar hell/Dll hell are not things I'd experienced, so I'll definitely take them into consideration in the future!

Comment: actually @MattD jar files are loaded per program where as dll files I believe share one memory across all programs. I was looking into this as a way to save memory for using multiple java applications with the same libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Google JAR files.

Edit: Wikipedia sums it up nicely: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29

> Software developers generally use .jar files to distribute Java applications or libraries...

Comment: Thank you very much.  I was aware full applications could be distributed in .jar files, but I did not realize they could act as libraries as well.

Answer (score 4):

A jar is just a uncompressed zip of your classes.  All classes can be easily decompiled and viewed.  If you really don't want to share your code, you might want to look at obfuscating your code.

Answer (score 2):

The Java analog to a DLL is the .jar file, which is a zip file containing a bunch of Java .class files and (perhaps) other resources.  See Sun's, er, Oracle's [documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/).

Answer (score 1):

Java's simple moto 'Write Once, Run anywhere'. create your all java classes as jar file but there are possibilities that still some one can see the Java code by using Decompilers. To prevent someone really looking at your code then Obfuscate the jar using the below link.

[Java Obfuscation](http://www.zelix.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You could publish a collection of compiled *.class files.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to package up Java code is to use a ".jar" file.  A .jar file is basically just a .zip file.

To distribute just your compiled code, you'll want to build a .jar that contains your .class files.  If you want to additionally distribute the source code, you can include the .java files in a separate area of the .jar.

There are a lot of tools and tutorials out there that explain how to build a .jar.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can compile Java bytecode down to native code and create a conventional DLL or shared library using an **[Ahead-Of-Time compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AOT_compiler)**.

However, that DLL would need the Java runtime specific to the AOT compiler, and two Java runtimes may not coexist in one process. Also, one would have to employ  **[JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)** to make any use of that DLL.

Unfortunately, **[obfuscation has too many weaknesses](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)**...

Answer (score 0):

your tittle doesn't match your comment....

simple have a source jar and a code jar. but, as other people pointed out you can obfuscate the code if you don't want people to read it, it's a pain for other people using your library as they would need the mappings in order to compile and the obfuscator.

```
A dll is a shared library (from what I read gets instantiated one time across multiple processes)
A jar is a shared library (code gets instantiated per process from the same file)
```

So to answer your title question there doesn't appear to be one built into java. A library could be made and then supported on all 3 major os's to have a dll equivalent version in java. But, the reason why java made it a new instance per program is for security / sanity reasons. there are custom class loaders, asm and reflection that other programs can modify the classes on load. So if your program does any of these things it could mess up other processes.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to distribute your source code. You can distribute compiled `.class` files, which contain human-unreadable bytecode. You can bundle them into `.jar` files, which are just zip files, and are roughly Java equivalent of native .dll files.

Note taht `.class` files can be easily decompiled (although decompilers cannot recover 100% of information from sources). To make decompilation more difficult, you can use obfuscator to make sources much less legible.

Comment: Bytecode is very human-readable, if you have a program that can read it... heck, _ASCII_ isn't human-readable unless you have a program that can read it!

Comment: Good point. ASCII readers are much more common than Java decompilers, though.